# What exactly is a rocker?

Tags: snowboarding

Snowboards are often described with the term "Rocker". It seems like a kind of shape or something.

What exactly is meant by a "Rocker" snowboard and what are the advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: It's the opposite of camber. A board with camber will curve with the tips towards the ground, a board with rocker will curve with the tips away from the ground.

Answer (score 3):

Rocker is a term common for freeride ski and snowboards. Because of the deep snow (powder) you need ski which are floating by design. That means it is easier to ride in powder with a higher rocker.

Rocker technically means the negative preload the ski/snowboard are having. So if you lay them on the ground without any load, the ski only touches the ground in the middle (where your binding lies) and not over the whole surface.

It seems that rockers also show advantages in halfpipes (freeskiing) and even on piste. So the technology is already widespread in winter sports.

Comment: side note: it is also a term in roller skating, where it is usually used as "anti rocker", which are wheel (smaller and set in position 2 and 3) designed to limit the rocking. When you put the roller skate on the ground, only the front and back wheels touch the ground, while the middle wheels don't - hence the term anit-rocker

Comment: another side note: the term has been used for decades to describe the same sort of curvature on surfboards, and I would presume was borrowed from that for snowboards. The amount of "rocker" to the shape is the amount of convex curve relative to a flat board.